# Question on upper bounds of two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a =5000$ to $1$ significant figure and $b=400$ to $1$ significant figure, calculate:

the upper bound of $$a-b$$

I thought the answer would be $5500 - 350 = 5150$ but the answers say it is $5750$; which is right?

Comment: What does s.f. mean?

Comment: What does a=5000 to 1 s.f. mean? I am not familiar with this notation. Does it mean that $a\in \{1,\cdots, 5000\}$ arbitrary?

Comment: significant figures

Comment: how many sf in the answer, i get 5999-400

Comment: it's the bound, 6000 would be the bound in your case, 5999 is not the maximum value, there could be 5999.9

Comment: are you sure the answer is a '7' not a '1' - they can look the same

Comment: 100% sure it is a '7'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a=5000 to 1 significant figure. By definition, this is $a\in [4500,5500)$. The same holds for $b$, i.e. $b\in [350,450)$.

Now we want an upper bound for $a-b$. As $a$ has a positive sign, we need to consider the biggest value of $a$ which is $a_{max} = 5500$. As $b$ has a negative sign, we need the least value of $b$, i.e. $b_{min} = 350$. Thus, $$a-b \leq a_{max} - b_{min} = 5150.$$

I think you were right, if my definition of significant figure is the right one.

Comment: what about for maximum value of $\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: Same argument, i.e. $5500/350 $

Comment: that's what I thought, thanks